# How to use a text element as part of two different capture groups in regex?

Tags: regex

I have a string I'm trying to parse with regex that seems to need one part of the string as a part of two different capture groups. Consider the following example:

```
<!-- 123 text -->text bit 1<!-- /123 text -->
<span class="someclass">something</span>
<!-- 456 text -->222 text<!-- /456 text -->
```

In this example code, I want three capture groups:

- everything up to (but not including) the 222 in the last line
- the 222 (or, the 222 plus its trailing space)
- the rest

The easiest unique piece of this is the `-->` followed by some number, so I thought of starting like this:

```
(.*-->\d+)
```

This would correctly find the right area, but I need that first capture group to be without the number and the second to have it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this work for you

```
(.*-->)(\d+)(.*)
```